# How to take the first ten records from a DataView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

I have a System.Data.DataView object but only want the first ten records, sorted by a column called "responseTime".

```
DataView dv = Factory.GetDataView("something");
dv.Sort = "responseTime desc";

// now what?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you could use a LINQ query. Something like:

var query = (from row in dv select row).Take(10)